# How to define a function as summation of other function with their respected parameters and fitting the parameters [python]

Tags: python, function, scipy, regression, curve-fitting

I would like to define a function which is define as a sum over other functions.
For instance, if 4 objects are bonded to each other by a harmonic potential. Assume the total potential is defined as a summation of pairwise interaction of each object with other objects.

[image]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import numpy as np

def func(r, kb, b0):
     return kb * (r - b0)**2
def total(r):
    sum_int=0
    for i in range(0,4):
        for j in range(0,4):
            if j == i:
                interaction = 0 # no self interaction
            else:
                interaction = func(r,globals()["kb_" + str(i) + str(j)],globals()["b0_" + str(i) + str(j)]) #pair energy
            sum_int = sum_int + interaction
    return sum_int

if __name__ == "__main__":
    xdata = [1.3,1.35,1.4,1.45,1.5,1.55,1.6,1.65,1.7]
    ydata = [-136.82,-164.87,-181.16,-188.53,-189.10,-184.49,-175.96,-164.51,-150.95]
    x = np.array(xdata)
    y = np.array(ydata) 
    plt.plot(x, y, 'bo', label='data')

    popt, pcov = curve_fit(total, xdata, ydata)
    print("Harmonic parameters")
    diff=sum(abs(func(x, popt[0], popt[1]) - y)) / len(x)
    print("AAE is")
    print(diff)
    plt.plot(xdata, func(xdata, *popt), 'r-',label='Hook: kb=%5.3f, b0=%5.3f' % tuple(popt))
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()
```

I have crudely coded, this problem and the function seems to work.
However, when I try to fit the function to the test data the curve_fit is unable to find the parameters to fit.

> ValueError: Unable to determine number of fit parameters.

Is this the correct way to define the function?
If so, how can I fix the problem with the curve_fit?

Comment: What are `globals()["kb_" + str(i) + str(j)]` and `globals()["b0_" + str(i) + str(j)]` supposed to be? Perhaps they can be passed as parameters to total and used as parameters for curve fitting?

Comment: those will be the parameters to be fitted kb_01, kb_02, kb_03, ....
this was the only way I found to pass undefined number of parameters to the total functional.
so If I have 10 interacting objects instead of 4, object 0 would have 2 parameter (kb and b0) with the 9 other objects.

Comment: I think the problem lies in these k and b0 parameters. They should be passed to the function `total`. How about passing each of them as an 2d array with a shape (n,n) where n is the number of objects. Then you could point `curve_fit` to the kb and b0 parameters and everything would fall into place.

Comment: How can I define a 2d array of unknown? I thought in python you are forced to define the the elements of the array. If I define the elements of the array by randoms or zeros then curve_fit wouldn't find them again?

Comment: I tried np.empty with no success

Comment: I've written [a gist](https://gist.github.com/jagaudin/9c281e42d0b629035f57a65c89c949a0) that may help you understand how `curve_fit` works. I recommend to have a look at [the examples in the documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html) too.